# log user's password in proftpd

Tags: proftpd

how can I log user's password in proftpd? I forgot his password so for now I set up anonymous login for his account to accept any password.
I want to find out his password and set it up with this correct password - but firstly I need to log it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems ProFTPD is explicitly designed to *not* log the password:

> Frequently Asked Questions
>
> Question: How can I configure proftpd to log/show the password typed by the user?
>
> Answer: You cannot. Period. The proftpd code goes out of its way to ensure that the password is never logged.

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Authentication.html

Answer (score 3):

If you need to find out the password of an active FTP account you can also use tcpdump

`sudo tcpdump src x.x.x.x and dst y.y.y.y and port ftp -A`